# How to read matrix from an ascii file

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, data-conversion

I am trying to read ascii text file as a matrix. The ascii file has 512 entries which are treated as rows and after each breakline character, a new row starts.
It looks something like [image]

I tried using

```
with open('24_5.asc', 'r') as f:
l = [[int(num) for num in line.split(',')] for line in f]
print(l)
```

but that gives an error

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\n'
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: @j1-lee It give the error "cannot assign to function call"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem here is that when you split a line the last element of the list returned will be a string `"\n"`, which cannot be converted to int. So Removing it with `[:-1]` should work:

```py
with open('24_5.asc', 'r') as f:
    l = [[int(num) for num in line.split(',')[:-1]] for line in f]
    print(l)
```